# input() acts weird with exclamation marks (!) in Spyder IDE

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, spyder

The `input()` function returns strange values on some inputs in the Spyder IDE with WinPython 3.3.5:

```
>>>input('say:')
say:hello
hello
>>>input('say:')
say:hello!
hello!
>>>input('say:')
say:!
'evalsc(r"!")'
>>>input('say:')
say:!123
'evalsc(r"!123")'
>>>s = input('say:')
say:!
>>>type(s)
<class 'str'>
>>>repr(s)
'\'evalsc(r"!")\''
```

Why `input()` processes leading exclamation with such strange way?

Interesting that if I run same python from a command line, all works correct.
But, within Spyder IDE, it plays me fool.

Comment: Perhaps this IDE overrides `input()`? If you just type `input` you should normally see `<built-in function input>`; is this different in the IDE shell? You can also check `__builtins__.input == input`; this should be `True`.

Comment: I believe the Spyder IDE uses the IPython console where lines starting with an `!` have a special meaning -- execute the rest of the line in a shell.

Comment: No, `input == __builtins__.input` - this is first I've checked :)
The problem is deeper.

In standalone IPython console it works as well as in standalone Python console.

Comment: I found this issue in the bugtracker of Spyder: https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=1568 - and commented there. Looks like the bug in the Spyder IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(*Spyder dev here*) This is a bug. We use `!` in our Python (*not* IPython) consoles to run some special commands that don't correspond to valid Python syntax (e.g. `!ls` to list files in the current working directory).

There is an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=1568) open for it. We'll try to fix it in our next release (2.3.3).

Comment: This is a dublicate of older bug https://code.google.com/p/spyderlib/issues/detail?id=1568 that appears in both 2.x and 3.x python versions of Spyder.

Comment: Anyway, thank you for attention. When do you expect to release next version?

Comment: Ups, I didn't notice it. I updated the answer accordingly. I hope to release 2.3.3 in a month and a half or two months. But you can use the IPython console in the meantime. I'm really thinking to deprecate our Python console in the future because maintaining our own console is a lot of our work.